# "Unable to build entity manager factory" Hibernate exception when running a jar file compiled with Maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I've created a Java 8 SE application with multiple dependencies, and i use Maven to supply the required libraries; it also uses JPA 2.2 and Hibernate 4.3.6, both supplied through maven, and when running it from Intellij it works fine;

I need to package it and run it on a remote Linux server, when i try to compile it through Maven (mvn compile assembly:single), it correctly creates a jar with dependencies, but when i run it both on my local machine or the remote server, the application fails as soon as it needs to connect to the database with the following error:

```
Apr 08, 2019 10:28:42 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: my-jpa-pu
        ...]
Apr 08, 2019 10:28:42 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Apr 08, 2019 10:28:42 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 08, 2019 10:28:42 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at dao.BattleDAO.getGameDate(BattleDAO.java:34)
        at controller.BattleController.doBattle(BattleController.java:38)
        at controller.WarBot.main(WarBot.java:95)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at util.PersistenceManager.<init>(PersistenceManager.java:12)
        at util.PersistenceManager.<clinit>(PersistenceManager.java:7)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:723)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:69)
        ... 7 more
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.kylesdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>warbot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>22-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>boundless</id>
            <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.postgis/postgis-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.restfb/restfb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
            <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>WarBot</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>controller.WarBot</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and this is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="my-jpa-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>model.AzioneEntity</class>
        <class>model.CatturaEntity</class>
        <class>model.QuartiereEntity</class>
        <class>model.TerritorioEntity</class>
        <class>model.TerritoriopossedutoEntity</class>
        <class>model.ConfineEntity</class>
        <class>model.UtilsEntity</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/warbot" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/warbot"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/warbot"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/warbot"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/warbot"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The database url is the correct one, as it's running on that specific machine, and i normally create a port tunnel through SSH when running the application on my local machine

**EDIT**

This is the class that handles the database connection:

```
package util;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
public enum PersistenceManager {
    INSTANCE;
    private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
    private PersistenceManager() {
        // "jpa-example" was the value of the name attribute of the
        // persistence-unit element.
        emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-jpa-pu");
    }
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
    public void close() {
        emFactory.close();
    }
}
```

and this method is the first to be called that accesses the database, which fails when run in the jar:

```
public static UtilsEntity getGameDate() {
        EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.INSTANCE.getEntityManager();
        UtilsEntity gameDate = (UtilsEntity) em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UtilsEntity u WHERE u.name = 'GAME_DATE'").getSingleResult();
        em.close();
        return gameDate;
    }
```

**EDIT 2:** i posted the wrong Database-class here, fixed with the right one

Comment: Could you show us your code, how you are trying to connect to the database?

Comment: @M.Ismail i've edited my post adding the class that connects to the database and a DAO method that calls it, it works when running through Intellij but fails when running from the compiled jar

Comment: If It works with Intellij, first try to verify the command you are using to build your project while hosting your application in the remote server.

Comment: It works with Intellij on my local machine (which runs Windows 10), if i try to compile it to a jar and run it locally it doesn't work anymore, i cannot test it with Intellij on the remote server as it's running linux and doesn't have a GUI

Comment: To build a maven project Intellij run some commands on the system, to do so you need to run the same commands Intellij does.

Comment: The DBSource class you posted tries to open a direct JDBC postgresql connection, while it seems you are using jpa/hibernate (and its initialization is what it fails looking at logs). Have you checked in your persistence.xml that username and password are correct (you probably changed them here in the question, but they differ).

Comment: @guido I posted the wrong class, that was my first try with a normal JDBC connection, i edited the post so you can now see the correct class (user and password are modified here but they are the correct ones in the persistence.xml)

Comment: ok thanks; try to run `mvn dependency:tree` and see how many times and what versions you get of javassist. Then unzip the assembled jar-with-dependency.jar and check what javassist you got in there. The version of javassist is the most common cause of this problem.

Comment: Hibernate 4.3.6 implements JPA 2.0, not 2.2.